# How to remote execute powershell commands with pipes by using invoke-expression?

Tags: powershell, wmi

For my work I need to retrieve the OS information from certain servers and stock that information on a certain server. I'd like to do this with powershell and use wmi to get the information.
All the servers have powershell installed, and a SSH connection between both is possible.

The easiest approach would probably be to execute remote powershell commands, but then I need to activate on every server the remote services and I would like to avoid that.
Another approach is using the command in PS: "Invoke-Expression", while using plink to connect.
It's this approach I'd like to use. I found a lot of information about it and I discovered how to use it to execute remote shell commands and even remote powershell commands (while placing "powershell" before the command).

This works:

```
$output = Invoke-Expression 'echo y | & "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh  $username@$hostname -pw $password "powershell gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem"'
```

But it doesn't give the information I need.
Instead of using "`gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem`" I want to use "`gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | select-object caption`", that should give me the information I need.
However I'm stuck with the quotes, whatever I tried I can't get this working, I always get an error with that select-object part. I tried looking at the internet for this, but I didn't find anything. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Regards,

Matthias

Comment: Have you tried: "powershell &{gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem|select caption}"